# How should you mock classes you don't own in Objective C/Cocoa? (eg NSDate)

Tags: objective-c, mocking

There's a rule that says

> Only mock objects that you own.

I think I understand the reason for this - mocking classes supplied by the frameworks might result in strange behaviour.

**What's the alternative?**

What about when you need a dummy date using NSDate?

In the past I've swizzled the date method from NSDate to my own class - NSDateMock - but something tells me that's really wrong!

**One Solution - A Wrapper?**

Create a wrapper round NSDate, but then you'd have to implement all it's methods.

Or would you just implement the ones you were using? It seems a messy way of doing it.

**My Question**

What's a good way of mocking classes you don't own such as NSDate?

**Update 1**

I found [this article on mocking](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/12/13/tdd-only-mock-types-you-own/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+MarkNeedham+%28Mark+Needham%29) which seems to imply that writing a thin wrapper is the way to go. I'm not quite sure why but I feel like this is a hack. Then again, it could make the code more expressive.

But that raises the question, in the case of NSDate do you inject the wrapper class into every single class that needs to know the date?! Surely not...

**Update 2**

There have been some good answers on this question, but I'm still holding out for other answers - there must be a definitive way of doing this, surely? I still don't see how categories are going to give me a dummy object I can control either.

Comment: Just curious - why do you want to create mock dates?  Without knowing anything else about your setup, my first thought is wondering why you need to mock a well-tested system class in the first place.

Comment: @Tim If an application is dealing with time sensitive operations I might want to simulate what happens, say, close to midnight. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general this is a "how to mock a static/class level method" question, which googling shows a lot of different ideas, so it mainly comes down to taste.

I consider partial mocks to be a code smell as it shows that your class under test (CUT) isn't testable -> time to refactor.

I've tackled this in 2 ways in the past:

1.) Pass a DateProvider (which is an interface) into the constructor of the CUT

```
interface DateProvider 
    date timenow()
end
```

At test time this is your MockDateProvider which you can change the state from your test class.  I might use a public static field that I can change in my tests

```
class MockDateProvider :: DateProvider
   public static field fakeDate   
   date timenow () 
      return fakedate
   end
end
```

In the real system it just has the date creation method you used.

```
class RealDateProvider :: DateProvider
   date timenow()
      return LibraryDateMaker.newDate()
   end
end
```

I might make 2 constructors, one that takes this interface and another which uses the RealDateProvider without any production classes needing to pass in the object.

This is the preferable OO way of doing things.  I think!

2.) Make your own static date provider that you can override the behaviour of.

Rather than LibraryDateMaker.newDate() you make a ConfigurableDateMaker.newDate() static.  This uses the same objects as 1, but has a setter to allow you to change the behaviour to the mock provider as required.  Defaulting to real.

The advantage of this is you don't have to pass anything into your constructors and you get to keep using a static method for a very common activity.

In brief, the CUT calls ConfigurableDateMaker.newDate().  Which by default returns a real date, but in your test class you can set the behaviour to use the mock before calling the CUT.

```
class ConfigurableDateMaker
  public static DateProvider provider
   static date timenow()
      return provider.newDate()
   end
   // add the 2 provider classes as inner classes in here
end
```

Hopefully that makes some sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead create a category of `NSDate` and implement an additional method such as

```
[NSDate mockDate];
```

There is no need to create a whole new class.

Comment: And then... swizzle the real date method for the mock one? But how would I specify what the mock date should return - categories can't have instance variables...

Comment: Seems dirty, but you could just use your own `[NSDate mockDate]` everywhere, and for test cases just return your own date. In all other cases it should simply return `[NSDate date]`

Comment: I don't understand how this would work. [NSDate mockDate] everywhere would mean I'd still have to swap this out for a method that returned my own date, meaning I'd still have to swizzle (which I'm trying to avoid) - surely this would add extra complexity to just swizzling the real date method with no real return? Plus my code would be littered with [NSDate mockDate] which is confusing!

Comment: You only have to swap it out in the declaration (i.e. in the category) and it applies to all your implementations.

Comment: Here is another possible solution: Create a NSDate category, that overrides `+ (NSDate *)date` with your proposed test-date and only `#import` this category for testing purposes. Taking this approach, you don't have to change anything in your main code.

Comment: Sorry to keep picking holes... but how would this know what the proposed test date was? Surely that would require a singleton and I hate using singletons except in very rare cases...

Comment: `+ (NSDate *)date
{
 return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
}` This, well, returns the date of 1970 (beginning of UNIX-Time). To change the test date, just modify the return-statement. (If I have understood your question correctly)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7920/discussion-between-john-gallagher-and-fscheidl)

Answer (score 1):

What specific problem are you trying to solve by mocking `NSDate`? In general, it should never be necessary to mock a value object like `NSDate`. Its interface provides easy ways to create an object representing any given date/time.

You could create a convenience method in your test class for generating the dates you need:

```
-(NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)dateString {
    // short style is 2/20/12 10:05 AM
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    return [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
}

-(void)testTimer {
    NSDate *startTime = [self dateFromString:@"2/20/12 11:58 PM"];
    NSDate *endTime = [self dateFromString:@"2/21/12 12:02 AM"];
    // pass dates into your timer method
}
```

Alternatively, if you need to test a method that gets the current time directly, you could provide a thin wrapper around `[NSDate date]`:

```
-(NSDate *)now {
    return [NSDate date];
}

-(void)startTimer {
    self.startTime = [self now];
}

-(void)stopTimer {
    NSDate *endTime = [self now];
    // ... do something 
}
```

Then, in your test, you mock your thin wrapper with a partial mock:

```
-(void)testStopTimer {
    Timer *timer = [[Timer alloc] init];
    timer.startTime = [self dateFromString:@"2/20/12 11:58 PM"];

    id mockTimer = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:timer];
    [[[mockTimer stub] andReturn:[self dateFromString:@"2/21/12 12:01 AM"] now];

    [timer stopTimer];

    // verify expected behavior...
}
```

Comment: Example from my app: I have log entries for time that the user spent on a document. A timer class has a start and stop method. I want to simulate what happens when I start the timer just before midnight and stop it just after in a test. There are a ton more potential examples - any class whose behaviour depends on the current time.

Comment: But this depends on the method under test having times injected into it. So I guess your solution is "pass in objects that are instances of classes you don't own instead"

Comment: I'm not sure I'd put it that generally, but in this case it seems a reasonable constraint. If you're testing after the start and stop have been called, those dates must be stored somewhere. If you don't like that, an alternative that follows the "thin wrapper" line would be for your method to call an internal method like `-(NSDate *)now` instead of `[NSDate date]`. Then your test can create a partial mock of the timer class and mock `now` to return whatever is convenient.

Comment: Another reason I'm reluctant to do this is because, as I understand it, to encapsulate objects properly you should be minimising passing around lots of parameters. The dates I use are stored somewhere, but when I call "stopTiming" for example, I do [NSDate date] to get the current time. If I passed the current time into this method, it would get pretty messy would it not?

Comment: Not necessarily. If your timer class has startTime and endTime properties, `stopTiming` would set endTime. Then your test could also set startTime and endTime, and test whatever it is you're trying to test. Or are you trying to test the `stopTiming` method itself?

Comment: Yeah - I'm trying to test stopTiming so that we check that on midnight overlaps it functions correctly.

Comment: In that case, I'd use a wrapper method and a partial mock. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks chrispix - great code. I'm just waiting to see if there's a way that doesn't involve partial mocking - not a fan of it. But if it get's the job done... I guess it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this gets at what you are trying to do, but when I've run into similar situations I've done something like the following:

1. Whenever I have a class that depends on some class that I might want to later mock out,
   I encapsulate access to that class within a method of my class. For example, instead of
   calling [NSDate date] to get current time, I would implement a method called currentTime.
   The implementation of that method would simply return [NSDate time].
2. I execute my test against a "partial mock" object created from my object under test, 
   stubbing the currentTime method to return my preferred test value rather than allowing 
   the real currentTime implementation from getting invoked.

I am using the OCMock framework to do all this, so it looks something like:

```
NSDate *testDate = // put whatever you want here
id mockTestObject = [OCMock partialMockForObject:testObject];
[mockTestObject stub] andReturn:testDate] currentDate];

[mockTestObject doSomethingThatUsersCurrentTime];
[mockTestObject verify];
```

OCMock provides a lot of different variants for stubbing, and I've found it works very well for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

### Q: How to mock a class you don't own?

### A: Just like a class you own.

**Example: Mocking `NSDate:timeIntervalSince1970` to return a known value**

Staying away from opinion-based responses, and focusing on a solution, say that you have the following invocation that you want to control in order to return a known value:

```
[[NSDate new] timeIntervalSince1970]]
```

…you can mock the `new` method to return anything you want, including `nil` **†**.
The following example first creates a `NSDate` with **42**, used in the `OCMStub`:

```
// Prepare a known date
NSDate * life = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:42];

// Mock the entire NSDate class, and stub `new`
id mockDate = OCMClassMock([NSDate class]);
OCMStub([mockDate new]).andReturn(life);

NSLog(@"%f",[[NSDate new] timeIntervalSince1970]); // "42.000000"

[mockDate stopMocking];
```

**Notes**

- Do not forget `stopMocking`!
- (**†**) This is probably why it is recommended to

  > only mock objects that you own.